# Keep QTableView scrolling to the last row when the model is growing

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtableview, autoscroll

I've a QTableView in a pyqt application. I continuously append rows to the underlying model. And what I want is the view to continuously scroll to the last, most recent row (is that behavior called "autoscrolling"?). But instead, the view does not scroll at all (automatically) and stays at its position.

Can I enable this autoscrolling behavior somehow or do I need to code something to achieve it?

Cheers,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default autoscrolling feature, but you can get the behavior relatively simple. Your model will emit `rowsInserted` when you insert/append rows. You can connect to that signal and call `scrollToBottom` on your view.

There is one problem though. View needs to adjust itself, because it won't put the item at the bottom *immediately* when `rowsInserted` fires. Calling `scrollToBottom` within a `QTimer.singleShot` solves this because `QTimer` will wait until there are no pending events (like update of the view).

Assuming the model is stored as `self.model` and view is `self.view`, this is how it'll look:

```
self.model.rowsInserted.connect(self.autoScroll)
```

and the `autoScroll` method:

```
def autoScroll(self):
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.view.scrollToBottom)
```

Or if you prefer not having a seperate method for this:

```
self.model.rowsInserted.connect(lambda: QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.view.scrollToBottom))
```

Comment: Okay, that works, thank you very much. However, maybe you can help me to understand the difference between `self.connect(self.statsModel, SIGNAL("rowsInserted()"), lambda: QTimer.singleShot(0, self.table.scrollToBottom))` (which does not work) and `self.statsModel.rowsInserted.connect(lambda: QTimer.singleShot(0, self.table.scrollToBottom))` which works. According to your explains I was under the impression that I have to connect to the signal rowsInserted of the model and call scrollToBottom on my view using the singleShot timer. Isn't that what I've done with the first code snippet?

Comment: @wollud1969: If you're going to use the _old syntax_ you need to give the correct signature for the signal, and the signature for `rowsInserted` is [`rowsInserted(QModelIndex, int, int)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted). But, that's the beauty of [new syntax](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html). You don't need to care about it :).

Comment: Understood! Thank you very much, I will learn about the new syntax and change all my code in this project accordingly.